# Does my dogs neuter incision look ok?

Tags: dogs, infections

It’s been exactly a week since his surgery. There has been very minimal swelling and the skin surrounding the cut never bruised or turned red. There is only scabbing over the incision but in one area it looks thick and is peeling off a little bit and underneath it looks red. Is this normal or should I take him back to the vet? Also His appetite is normal and he’s still playful as usual.[image]

Comment: If you're concerned, you should at least give your vet a call to find out if you should go in or not.

Comment: i can not see any sign of problems it looks to me like it is closing up nicely,i can not see any signs of infection or redness of the skin but to be sure make a call to your vet he/she will know what questions to ask,it is always best to ask your vet first as an answer here might take some time,and most of us are not professinals.

Comment: I second the comments here, it looks ok but see the vet if you’re worried. I just want to add that if it is infected and he'll let you touch it, it will be warmer than the rest of him.